# Postscript - alternative approach for case statement

Tags: postscript

I occasionally dabble with postscript, it is a quirky language I like, but I am far from expert.

To produce diagrams like this:

[image]

I have written some code that looks like this:

```
  % fontsize on stack

  label (Up) eq 
    { /Symbol exch selectfont (\255) show }
    { label (Down) eq 
      { /Symbol exch selectfont (\257) show }
      { label (Left) eq
        { /Symbol exch selectfont (\254) show }
        { label (Right) eq
          { /Symbol exch selectfont (\256) show }
          { label (bs) eq
            { /Symbol exch selectfont (\254) show }
            { /Helvetica exch selectfont 
              label length 3 lt 
                { label show }
                {
                  label (/)              % (page/up) (/)
                  search                 % (up) (/) (page) true
                  {                      % (up) (/) (page) 
                    /Helvetica keyHeight 4.6 div selectfont
                    3 1 roll             % (page) (up) (/)
                    pop                  % (page) (up)
                    currentpoint         % (page) (up) 438 745
                    3 2 roll             % (page) 438 745 (up)
                    show                 % (page) 438 745 
                    moveto               % (page)
                    0 keyHeight 0.25 mul % (page) 0 11
                    rmoveto              % (page) 
                    show }               % 
                  { show } ifelse
                } ifelse 
            } ifelse
          } ifelse
        } ifelse
      } ifelse
    } ifelse
    ...
    (End)key (Page/Down)key 0.5 gap (7)(Home)key2 (8)(Up)key2 ...
```

I don't like the nested if statements and repetition but it was a first quick stab at a solution. My first thought was I'd use a case statement in another language. For Postscript I guess I should choose a suitable data structure for the pairs of label names and corresponding octal character codes. Perhaps a nested array.

```
  [ [(Up) (\255)]  [(Down) (\257)] ... ]
```

But I'm unsure how I could iterate over this and still elegantly keep track of whether I need to execute a default procedure when no names matched.

Is there a good idiom I could follow?

Comment: Sadly I'm away from my desk at the moment, if you check comp.lang.postscript archives you should find some posts there on this subject (look for code from me or luser droog if I remember correctly). Otherwise I'll post something here when I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK now I'm back at my desk. Rather than answer this myself let me point you at an excellent resource instead, John Deubert's [Acumen Training Journal](http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html):

If you look at the April 2001 PostScript tech journal you'll see John's clear description of how to implement the case statement using dictionaries. I'd suggest this is better than using arrays for two main reasons, firstly the ability to simply add a default case, and secondly the fact that the 'get' and 'known' operators are, as John points out, usually highly optimised in PostScript interpreters, as they are used very frequently.

Comment: The dictionary based `case` looks perfect for my needs! Also thanks for introducing me to the Acumen Training Journal.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach you could take for your specific use-case here is to define a combined font. It appears most of the text is being shown in Helvetica, but with a select few borrowed from Symbol. An [example program here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/output-a-playable-crossword-grid/3948#3948) shows that you can select a font and use it within the BuildChar procedure of a custom Type-3 font. It may still require a case statement to implement, but lets the actual application usage be much nicer.

Here's a draft.

```
%lo-font threshold hi-font  .  <<derived font>>
/splitfont {
    4 dict begin {hi-font threshold lo-font}{exch def}forall
        /width .9 def 
    (<< 
        /FontType 3
        /FontBBox [ 0 0 //width 1 ] 
        /FontMatrix matrix
        /Encoding StandardEncoding % Lying to the postscript interpreter
        /BuildChar {
            %//width 0 0 0 //width 1 setcachedevice
            dup //threshold lt
                { //lo-font }{ //hi-font } ifelse
            1 selectfont
            (?)dup 0 4 3 roll put 
            dup stringwidth
            setcharwidth %2 index false charpath pathbbox setcachedevice
            show
            pop
        }
    >>) cvx exec
    end 
} def 

/Helv+Symb /Helvetica 8#254 /Symbol splitfont definefont pop 

/Helv+Symb 20 selectfont
100 100 moveto
(Text in Helvetica + \254\255\256\257) show
```